# How can I make an arrow shape to loop between a list of names by pointing at each name daily/weekly in Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, loops

[Image attached showing the cells I would like to apply the rule to within the workbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBwiH.jpg)Basically I'm trying to make an arrow or a color in a cell to move through a list of names in specific cells on daily or weekly basis in an Excel worksheet. The purpose is just for an indication to monitor and help memorize which name is the person's turn in the corresponding week.

Comment: It sounds like conditional formatting is what you're looking for.

Comment: Sure is condition formatting , send an example of your workbook with Images and we can help you more

Comment: I have added an image showing the cells I would like to apply the rule to in the question description. Its a very simple worksheet. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Please help @RonanVico